# How to get information from textarea to another PHP site

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a school project and cant gets this function to work. In my code a user should be able to insert their name and/or email in a textarea and when they press the update button the information should be updated in the MySql database. In order to understand the code I made two if statements that check if the value "updateUser" file gets is empty or not.

My select code:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["firstname"]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["email"]);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee where username ='$username'";

if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ //kollar/retunerar rows i result set
        echo "<table>"; //tabellen
        echo "<table border=1";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>firstname</th>";
                echo "<th>email</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //Fetch a result row as an array

            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<form class="" action="updateEmployee.php" method="post">'; 
                echo "<textarea >" . $row['firstname'] . "</textarea>";
                echo "<textarea>" . $row['email'] . "</textarea>";
                echo '<input type="submit" name="updateEmp" value="uppdatera">'; 
            echo "</form>";
            echo '</tr>';

        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        $_SESSION["email"] = "$email";
    $_SESSION["firstname"] = "$firstname";


    } else{
        echo "no user.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}



}
// Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="selectUser.php" method="post">
    username  <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="test">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My updated code:

```
 <?php
   include('connection.php');
   session_start();

   $firstname = $_SESSION["firstname"];
   $email = $_SESSION["email"];

if ($email == "") {

  echo "lname  ej"; 
}
if ($firstname == ""){
    echo "fname gick ej"; 
}
else {

  $sql_update = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE employee SET firstname = '$firstname', WHERE email = '$email'");

}

  mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

I'm quite new at PHP but have experience in Java and C#. Is the thought process the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what your expectation is and what is different? Are you receiving an error? See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is your question, exactly? By "another PHP site", do you mean another page on the same domain, or a different domain entirely?

Comment: you never set `$username` ?

Comment: Try adding to your textarea a name, because your post is probably getting empty, and in your update code change session for $_POST['nameinthetextarea']

Comment: PS: Don't forget to escape the row data you put in your html! If I provide </textarea><script>badStuff()</script><textarea> as username or email, bad stuff will happen to unsuspicious visitors..

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.